# Preposition usage

Tags: grammaticality

In these sentence ,
i am confusing about usage of being
1)I am pround of him for his being a student of my school 
     and being a resident of my area.
Is it grammatical and idiomatic 
I am waiting for yor valuable reply

Answer (score 1):

First, you almost certainly mean that you are "confused" rather than "confusing."

Your proposed sentence is grammatical, but it is not quite idiomatic U.S. English.

> I am proud of him for being a student in my school and being a resident of my area

would be better, but it still sounds quite wordy and stilted.

> I am proud of him for being a student in my school and a resident of my area

is still wordy. Moreover, the meaning might be better expressed by using a clause rather than a gerund.

> I am proud that he is a student in my school and a resident of my area.

Finally, even that version sounds stilted to me.

> I am proud that he is a student in my school and my neighbor.

Comment: .thank you.i was just experimenting .you are correct.i can't upvote you due to insufficient point in my account